# React Navigation and flow-typed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, flowtype

I just started using flow-typed definitions for my popular libraries in a React Native app such as React Navigation, but I find it quite hard to find the documentation on types and how to use them. I'm still getting errors in my IDE and I feel like Flow is more wasting my time than adding value to my developer experience because I've to lookup for the types all the time (and sometimes don't even find an answer). Any advice about that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complex web application using many npm modules is very rarely going to be strongly typed throughout. The goal of strong typing in JS is largely to have as much typing as is feasible or even reasonable. Modules which do not have libdefs will come in as `any` and that's *okay.* Obviously it would be great if everything you pulled in had full types, but just given the way that progress is made this is practically impossible. Add to this the fact that the simple act of upgrading flow will often introduce more caught errors to your codebase, and you end up having to accept that typing is a progressive process, it shouldn't really be a blocking one.

Now that that's out of the way, you seem to have a number of different sub-questions:

> I've to lookup for the types all the time

Not entirely sure what you mean by this, but you might saying it's hard to find types for the package you're using. Make sure you're familiar with how the `flow-typed` CLI tool works (`npx flow-typed`), it will help you with searching for and installing compatible libdefs. If you don't find anything for a module in `flow-typed` then poke around the source github repo and make sure flow types aren't shipped with the module itself. If you come across a package with a `.d.ts` (TypeScript) file, try converting it to a libdef with [flowgen](https://github.com/joarwilk/flowgen). If nothing proves fruitful, you should probably just forego types and carry on.

In this case, I would actually start my own libdef (`npx flow-typed create-stub <package name>`) and fill in some basic types as I went. You can start really simple, I have a libdef currently for `react-select` that only checks one prop of the component, the `options` prop (I don't remember why I have this, however :P). Again, progressive typing is the goal. Checking that one prop is actually really nice compared to checking none.

> I find it quite hard to find the documentation on types and how to use them

There's generally not real documentation for libdefs in `flow-typed` unless it's written by the package author somewhere. I usually read the libdefs themselves, but if you find usage confusing I would recommend looking at the [tests](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/%40react-navigation/core_v3.x.x/test_core.js) associated with the libdef. You can also dig through any [relevant issues or PRs](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=react-navigation) to find usage examples.

> sometimes don't even find an answer

Add a `$FlowFixMe` and come back to it later if it slows you down too much. All of these things will become much more manageable as you become more accustomed to flow and strong typing in general, and both flow and libdefs are constantly improving.

> I'm still getting errors in my IDE

If you can't fix them, add a `$FlowFixMe` and come back later. Flow actually has a tool included in its source code that has a utility for adding `$FlowFixMe` for every error, but as it's not currently shipped to npm you have to clone the source to use it.